# VB.NET thread synchronization of class property

Tags: vb.net, synchronization

I have a question about thread synchronization in VB.NET.

Suppose you have a list object as a private class member and expose it as a read-only property as so (notice the synchronization in the `Get` block):

```
Dim mySubmissionList As New List(Of Submission)

ReadOnly Property SubmissionList() As List(Of Submission)
  Get
    SyncLock mySubmissionList
      Return mySubmissionList
    End SyncLock
  End Get
End Property
```

In another method in the class, the list would be added to:

```
Public Sub AddSubmission(ByRef submsn As Submission)
  SyncLock mySubmissionList
    mySubmissionList.Add(submsn)
  End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Now, suppose you use this property in another class as such:

```
' CurrentSubmissions is an object of the class discussed above
For Each submsn In CurrentSubmissions.SubmissionList
  ' use submsn here...
Next
```

My question is, will mySubmissionList be synchronized for the whole `For` block? Basically, I wouldn't want `mySubmissionList` to be used by `AddSubmission` until the other class was done iterating.

Comment: Don't lock on data structures; you will leak implementation details, and the lock logic will be more difficult to reason about.  Instead, always provide a separate locking object.  See http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Choosing_the_Synchronization_Object for details.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense, don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. As a curiosity, do you know if what I have above would keep it locked or not?

Comment: It would be locked for each added submission. That might  be sufficient.  If you want to lock the entire `For` block in one go, you have to wrap the whole thing in a `SyncLock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good design.  The list class itself is not thread safe and there is no const concept as there is in c++ so any user of any thread could attempt to add to your list.  A simple solution is to use one the of the thread safe collections like [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).  If that does not suite you could provide your own custom class with an custom enumerator that observes your lock.

Comment: So I am thinking I should include a locking variable in the class, and use it whenever calling a method of that class? Is there a data type designed specifically for this use?

Comment: Actually, what he is saying is that you should use one of the built-in concurrent collections already provided by the .NET framework for this purpose.

Comment: Okay, and do those concurrent collections provide thread safety for the objects in the collection as well? For instance, if I iterate over the collection and store a reference to one of the objects in it, then alter that object later, will the alterations also be thread safe?

Comment: That's a good question.  When you're adding an object to a thread-safe collection, what you are doing is adding a *reference* to that object to the collection in a threadsafe way (e.g. you can't reorder the collection while someone is adding an item to it).  When you are mutating an object in a threadsafe way, you are preventing the object's *values* from being mutated by another thread at the same time.  So the two things are not the same.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Thanks a lot for your help!